# How can I make my table of contents into an actual table?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

The template provided by a particular journal includes a "manual" table of contents:

```
\begin{large}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        1. Section 1 & 4. Section 4\\
        2. Section 2 & 5. Section 5\\
        3. Section 3 & 6. Section 6
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{large}
```

The goal is, presumably, to have the table of contents nicely aligned in two columns. And given that I don't have too many sections, I could just keep this updated by hand.

However, it seems like there should be a better way to do this, so that I don't need to manually update the table of contents every time I change a section name, and I automatically get the benefits of hyperref and such.

Is there a way to make `\tableofcontents` imitate this format?

Comment: (1) It is generally not a good idea to go against the Journal's template. (2) Have you tried using `multicol` package?

Comment: @WillieWong Right; my question is whether it's possible to have an automatic table of contents matching the journal's formatting. (If not I can just do it manually.)

Comment: Does their template include a literal `{tabular}{cc}`, or does the pdf just have the TOC in two columns?  The latter could be accomplished by `multicol`, as Willie Wong suggested.  More specifically, are you looking for a way to have the equivalent tex (possibly after some macros), or are you looking for a way to have similar output?

Comment: @Teepeemm The template has a literal `tabular` environment. Similar output should be good enough; I've considered multicol but I'm not sure how to make the items line up between columns like they do in a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sets the TOC within a multicols environment.  The catch is that you probably don't want "Contents" to be in the columns, so we use etoolbox to make the multicols start after the "Contents", but before the contents are actually read.  \raggedcolumns makes each TOC entry take its natural vertical height so that they have a better chance of lining up horizontally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@starttoc}{\begin{multicols}{2}}{}{}
\makeatother
\tableofcontents
\raggedcolumns
\end{multicols}

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\end{document}
```

[image: output TOC image]